# How to access Classroom Course Stream using Google Classroom API

Tags: android, google-classroom

I was finally able to access the Google classroom API from an Android app even though the Authorization flow used [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/java) doesn't work in an Android environment.

Now I can view all courses, the description etc but not the discussions in the Classroom (labeled **Stream** in the Google android Classroom app and Web App).

The Google classroom android app is so poor and buggy and always crashes that's why I decided to embark on this project.

So my question is how can I get this? I can't find such a call in the API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Stream** from Google Classroom is split into different elements so, depending on the type of elements you have and want to retrieve from the **Classroom Stream**, you might benefit from checking the following requests:

#### Retrieving the announcements

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/announcements
```

#### Retrieving the courseworks

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWork
```

#### Retrieving the coursework materials

```
GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWorkMaterials
```

#### Note

Also, please bear in mind that all these requests will return the information needed *only* if the user making the request *has access* and the *necessary permissions* for retrieving it.

The quickstart you mentioned is a Java one - so in order to make it work for Android you will have to adapt it properly to your needs.

#### Reference

- [Classroom API courses.announcements.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list);
- [Classroom API courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list);
- [Classroom API courses.courseWorkMaterials.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWorkMaterials/list).

Comment: Thanks, but what about Messges sent by participants